# Android, CountDownTimer latency

Tags: android

I'm using `CountDownTimer` like so:

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(30 * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            handleOnTick(millisUntilFinished);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            handleOnFinish();
            playSound(ALERT_SECOND_FINISH);
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

private void handleOnTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
    tvTime.setText(
            String.format(Locale.US,
                    "%d:%02d",
                    min, sec)
    );
}
```

The problem is when `handleOnTick` is called, `millisUntilFinished` is ~`29953` and `millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished / 1000` equals 29 while I'm expecting 30!
So how can I handle this latency without using `counter` value or so? I used `Bigdecimal` and `Rounding` but it still passes values less than `30000`.

Comment: timer = new CountDownTimer(400000, 1000) { //40000 milli seconds is total time, 1000 milli seconds is time interval

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            text_timer.setText(400-(millisUntilFinished/1000)+" sec");
                        }
                        public void onFinish() {
                        }
                    }.start();

Try something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `millisUntilFinished = Math.round(millisUntilFinished / 1000.0f);`